issue with Rich Text editor
Hi I have one issue with Rich Text editor,
when enter some text with some color( say red color ) + Bold + Italic then give one space and again select different color + bold then previous text color will get changed to black(original)
Any solution for this?
Tried to modified few parameters in jquery-te-1.4.0.js and jquery-te-1.4.0.css nothing happening

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before anyone will be able to help, they will need to see a [mcve]. Please provide one.
